# getting an error trying to allocate memory with malloc(reading violation) ,it sometimes works for the first couple strings,but it blows up eventually

Tags: c, malloc

> the function is supposed to make a list fill it and return head, it blows up when it reaches malloc, the compiler says that "temporary" might not be zero terminated which is not true any help?

```
std* FromFileToList(std* head, FILE* in) {
    int i;
    std* temp;
    char temporary[257], c;

    do {
        if (!(temp = (std*)malloc(sizeof(temp)))) {
            DeleteList(head);
            Error_Msg("Memory allocation Error!");
        }
        fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %d %d %d", temp->code, temporary, temp->Dep, &temp->marks[0], &temp->marks[1], &temp->marks[2]);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            temp->avg += (float)(temp->marks[i] / 3);
        temp->name = (char*)malloc((strlen(temporary) + 1) * (sizeof(char)));//Error here
        if (!(temp->name)) {
            DeleteList(head);
            Error_Msg("Memory allocation Error!");
        }
        strcpy(temp->name, temporary);[enter image description here][1]
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        c = fgetc(in);
    } while (c != EOF);
    return(head);
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(temp))` -> `malloc(sizeof(*temp))` or `malloc(sizeof(std))`

Comment: Do you understand my first comment? That is a big problem and is likely a major cause of "sometimes works but sometimes blows up". Regarding the specific error, please show the exact error msg from the compiler. It may be complaining that you are not checking the return value of `fscanf`before using the results. If `fscanf` fails then `temporary` may contain garbage.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked, i just didn't get your first comment for some reason :'D